# Is it right about JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a question about `KNilOptions` and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.
i thank they have a same function.
Because `KNilOptions` Equal to Zero and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` too.

is it right?

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

// `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers is equal to kNilOptions`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the definition of `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`:

```
NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
```

So `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` is defined as 1, **not** 0. It does not have the same value as `kNilOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

First the small introduction about `KNilOptions` and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.
`KNilOptions` stand for 0 and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` is stand for `(1UL << 0)` in enum.

So in the `C++,` UL just means the literal is an `unsigned long` integer type. The default integer literal is `int`.

This both (`KNilOptions` and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`) will help in the options for reading the `JSON` data and creating the Foundation objects.

You can create the dictionary from the JSON string with the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option, which creates all arrays and dictionaries as mutable objects so that you can add a new key in object (Dictionary) and add new Dictionary in your array without changing in the reference and you will get the full mutable structure.